# How to set correctly the line sizes in a ggplot 2 theme?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, width, axis

I have a plot with a border using `ggplot2`. In the `theme` I specified the axis and the border size with the same value (0.35). However, when I save the plot as `.SVG`, the line sizes have not the same size. How can I solve this?

```
library(ggplot2)

x1 <- c(52.67, 46.80, 41.74, 40.45)
y1 <- c(1.726219351, 1.842421805, 1.790801758, 1.449997494)

DF <- data.frame(x1, y1)

svg(
  filename = "example.svg",
  width = 3.55
)

ggplot(DF, aes(x1, y1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1,
        panel.border = element_rect(color = 2, size = 0.35, fill = NA),
        axis.line = element_line(color = 1, size = 0.35))

dev.off()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem exactly. Could you add `+ coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` and see if the problem persists?

Comment: It solves the problem, thank you